# I am creating a procedure seemingly correctly, however I am receiving a SQL syntax error

Tags: sql, mariadb, syntax-error, procedure

The following code:

```
USE `securityMisconfigStealToken`;
-- DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `securityMisconfigStealToken`.`getToken`(IN theUserId VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
DECLARE tokenExists INT;
COMMIT;
SELECT count(token) FROM `securityMisconfigStealToken`.`tokens` WHERE userId = theUserId INTO tokenExists;
IF (tokenExists < 1) THEN
        INSERT INTO tokens (userId, token) VALUES (theUserId, SHA2(CONCAT(RAND(), now()), 256));
        COMMIT;
END IF;
SELECT token FROM tokens WHERE userId = theUserId;
END
;
-- $$
```

Throws the exception:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 996: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
> the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

I am currently using mariaDB version 10.5.12.

The first line of code starts at line 994 and ends at 1008, however the error refers to syntax at line 3. I cannot seem to find at all why this code is throwing an error.

Comment: Why the `--` in front of the `DELIMITER` statement? 
`--` starts a comment, and so `DELIMITER` is basically ignored, leading to the syntax error. When properly starting with `DELIMITER $$` and ending with `$$` without the `--` prefix I can create the procedure just fine

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that I had those comments there, I had comments there previously and never removed the `--`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MariaDB Comment Syntax](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/comment-syntax/):

There are 3 supported comment styles in MariaDB:

1. ...
2. From a '-- ' to the end of a line. The space after the two dashes is required (as in MySQL).
3. ...

This means your delimiter will not be accepted, since it's a comment (And same with `-- $$` at the end).

Comment: Ah thank you! I had comments there previously and completely forgot to remove the `--` in front of the `DELIMITER`. Thank you!